# Improve speed of 'Load data infile' for InnoDB in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to find a way to improve performance of 'Load data infile' command for InnoDB table, which is extremely slow. Generally I have been using MyISAM for more than 10 years, because this engine by design is the best option for tables with rare writes (once per day without concurency) and many reads (select queries). But with the time MyISAM has been left in the corner in favour of InnoDB. I decided to give InnoDB a try, because I would like to use partitioning. And this was the point when my headaches started with the attempts to achieve reasonable speed for loading of data.

My table has 860 columns and it cannot be normalized, because all columns are with equal priority and all of them are used to generate a result set from a query. The table has 4 indexes and a primary key, which consists of 2 columns - object and time. Every day about 80k rows are being inserted in the table, which results of close to 100 million rows for 3 years time. **Edit**: More information about the table's structure can be found at the end of the question. No partitioning was implemented at the moment.

I did a few experiemnts playing with differents parameters and one MySQL tool. The experiment setup is the importing of 51000 rows in a blank InnoDB table with the properties mentioned above. The reference was the importing time in MyISAM table which was just 12 seconds. The best importing time that I achieved in the same table, but with InnoDB engine  was 12 minutes, meaning 60 times slower, which is not tolerable at all.

The steps I did for the experiment are listed below. Apparently something else should be possible to be done, but I am not aware what and any suggestions will be welcome. My aim is to get importing times close to the ones for MyISAM table, otherwise InnoDB will be of no use to me.

1. Importing time - 17 min 09 sec:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 /* (the default value) */
innodb_buffer_pool_size=0.125 GB /* (the default value) */
```

2. Importing time - 12 min 04 sec:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 /* (the default value) */
innodb_buffer_pool_size=7 GB /* (out of 8 GB available) */
```

3. Importing time - 11 min 59 sec:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=7 GB /* (out of 8 GB available) */
```

4. Importing time - 11 min 47 sec:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=7 GB /* (out of 8 GB available) */
```

5. Importing time - 10 min 59 sec:

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=7 GB /* (out of 8 GB available) */
/* all indexes were deleted prior to importing */
```

6. Importing time - 03 min 15 sec (the fastest but not a usable solution):

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=7 GB /* (out of 8 GB available) */
/* all indexes were deleted prior to importing */
/* primary key was deleted prior to importing */
```

As can be seen above most improvement provides the increase of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Some improvement can be achieved with disabling of indexes before importing and after it finishes to enable them again (but this process will take probably some additional time). Still the improvements are so minor compared to MyISAM table performance. Obviously most time is spent with dealing with primary key, but there is no option not to have it.

Further experiments:

7. Importing time - 14 min. Usage of util.import_table in MySQL shell. 4 threads were used for paralel imports. 2 attempts were made with innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1 and with innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2. Importing time was the same in both cases - 14 minutes.
8. Importing time - 13 min 20 sec. Usage of autocommit = 0 as suggested by MySQL documentation. Setup was with following parameters: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 and innodb_buffer_pool_size=7 GB

```
SET autocommit=0;
Load data infile '//Import_tools//process_hua//export1.csv' into table testdb.h_cell_inno FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
COMMIT;
```

**Edit**: One more experiment was done with reduced number of columns. I left just 60 out of 860 columns in the table and also shortened the input CSV file to contain just 60 records per row. Results: Importing to MyISAM table took 2 seconds and to InnoDB it took 50 seconds. (Setup was with following parameters: innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2 and innodb_buffer_pool_size=6 GB)

Worth mentioning is another comparison between MyISAM and InnoDB importing. After the first loading of data to MyISAM table every next import of 51k rows took approximately the same time - bteween 8 and 10 seconds. But when I loaded one more chunk of 51k rows to the InnoDB table it took more than twice the time spent to inject the first portion - 26 min vs. 12 min. This is also quite a problem considering that the table will be populated with a lot of data.

**Edit**: Now the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW TABLE STATUS statements are included in the question. SHOW CREATE TABLE is shortend and is showing just a few columns with all the datatypes used.

```
CREATE TABLE `h_cell_inno` (
  `Time` date NOT NULL,
  `Site` int NOT NULL,
  `Cell` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `LocalCI` int NOT NULL,
  `Object` int NOT NULL,
  `Integrity` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `Counter1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `Counter2` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `Counter3` double DEFAULT NULL,
  .................. 
  `Counter863` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Cell`,`Time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Index1` (`Cell`,`Time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Index2` (`Site`,`CI`,`Time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Index3` (`Time`,`CI`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

```
| Name        | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options     | Comment |
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
| h_cell_inno | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 36741 |           7756 |   284983296 |               0 |      8454144 |   6291456 |           NULL | 2024-01-17 11:04:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |     NULL | row_format=DYNAMIC |         |
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+
```

Is there anything else which I could do to improve the speed of data loading in InnoDB? If not should I change MySQL database (like PostgreSQL for example), which could provide better import speeds, ACID and partitioning, while keeping select queries fast enough?

Comment: 7GB is too tight; there may be swapping.  Try 6GB.  Also, please show us the indexes involved.

Comment: Is the input sorted by the PK before doing `LOAD`?

Comment: And provide the `PARTITION` definition; it may be hurting more than helping.

Comment: How big is one row (in bytes)?  Is this sensor data?  What datatype is being used for the values?  Are they the smallest that is practical for what is being measured?

Comment: Can the 960 columns be broken into logical groups?  I'm worried that the BTree has only one row per block.  I've never seen that many columns; I suspect that it is a significant part of the problem.

Comment: Are some of the columns really an "array"?  If so, let's talk about workarounds.  I can of a few.

Comment: If you don't care about ACID (which you must not given that you used MyISAM), then just use MySQL's [CSV storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html).

Then there's no import time at all. Just physically move a source CSV file into the data directory. Voilà, you can query the CSV data with SQL.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE testdb.h_cell_inno; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "h_cell_inno"; for analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have just updated my question with the requested by you information.

Comment: @RickJames I made an experiemnt with buffer size of 6GB, but there was no change in importing time - it was still around 12 minutes. My question was edited with the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE statement. No partitioning was involved in the experiments (this is supposed to be in the next steps). I need to study the concept of sorting PK before importing, but I am not sure if it will work, because new data to be uploaded could be with older timestamp than the existing one in the table and also will come from different sources.

Comment: @RickJames Further experiment was done with reduced number of columns - just 60. Importing to MyISAM version of the table took 2 seconds and to InnoDB - around 60 seconds. Even if I break the table into several other tables, all 860 columns should end up in the database. Perhaps in this case there will be a gain in importing time if imports are done in parallel to multiple tables and also your concerns about BTree will be sovled. But when data is going to be queried from more tables I will need to join these tables and when queries are complex then SELECT time will increase.

Comment: One load a day -- What is the problem with the slow load?  Perhaps `SELECTs` are happening all the time?  Or something else?  Please provide a typical `SELECT`; perhaps I can gain more insight based on that.

Comment: @RickJames My first problem was that I wanted to create a large InnoDB test table to benchmark queries, but that was not possible because of the low speed of LOAD DATA. Provided that the database was a production one then the much slower speed to load the fresh daily stats for the day before would not be such a problem. But what I experienced with my experiments is that every next load is slower than the previous one as the table grows. So it might happen that in one moment the loads are so slow, so that to make the database unusable (this is just a specualation).

Comment: @RickJames Regarding a typical `SELECT` I created a new question, so if you would have a chance you could take a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77894204/how-to-properly-utilize-a-composite-index-in-join-queries). Please note that the used table is MyISAM.

Comment: @Ivaylo - For entirely MyISAM, set `key_buffer_size` to 20% of available RAM and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 0.  Vice versa:  30M and 0.  For a mixture of engines, use numbers somewhere in between.  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: "60 records per row" -- Usually a "record" and a "row" are synonyms; what do you mean by that phrase??

Answer (score 1):

The `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.  That is, your `Index1` is redundant and should be dropped.

What is `CI`?

If the data is "sensor type, the `DOUBLE` (8 bytes, 16 significant digits) is probably overkill; consider using `FLOAT` (4 bytes, 7 significant digits).

Similarly for `BIGINT` and `INT`.

Eh?  Rows seem to be inserted every second, but `Time` is only `DATE`?

`Cell` is up to 82 bytes; a good candidate for normalizing.

With so many columns, there may be only 1 or 2 rows per node in the BTree; shrinking the datatypes is very important.

Comment: You are totally right about the fact that Index1 is useless as it covers the PK (I adopted this wrong concept very long ago due to the query cache, which "lied" to me :) That is why Index1 was dropped. As you suggested I changed the DOUBLE type to FLOAT, wherever this was possible. Actually I am inserting daily values and this is done once per day, so DATE type of Time is just fine.

Comment: After the changes done in the previous comment I run the experiment again and I got some small gain - from 12:00 minutes importing time was reduced to 10:30. Unfortunately this is far away from MyISAM insertion performance, so most likely I will keep using MyISAM engine. Apparently InnoDB was designed for other scenarios and I am just wondering why MySQL devs gave up developing MyISAM engine as there are use cases for it.

Answer (score 1):

Ivaylo,
I totally agree with Rick James, INDEX1 is redundant and totally WASTES space in your table, CPU cycles for every insert of a row.  Delete INDEX1 from your table, please.

We need to find out more about your CELL column.  This query will answer my questions about data Maximum length and Average length, if you will let it run through your COMPLETE table content and post TEXT results.

## sel-MLALh_cell_inno.sql    MLAL   last upd 2024-01-18 WLH

## original 2024-01-18 WLH

## if this helps you, please email SHAREABLE comments to info@mysqlservertuning.com

SELECT
'Begin Time',NOW(),DATABASE(),' ',COUNT(*),' ',
MAX(LENGTH(cell)),AVG(LENGTH(cell)),'cell',' '
FROM testdb.h_cell_inno
\G;
SELECT '  End Time',NOW();

Comment: You are absolutely right about the redundancy of Index1 and it is alreday removed. The results from the first command you suggested: ```Begin Time: Begin Time, NOW(): 2024-01-19 19:47:16, DATABASE(): testdb, COUNT(*): 51519, MAX(LENGTH(cell)): 8, AVG(LENGTH(cell)): 8.0000, cell: cell```

Comment: With the Max and Avg length of 8,   A definition of CHAR(8) will have better performance and conserve 1 char per row when you QUIT using VARCHAR.  Consider the possibility.

Comment: Already done. As far as I understood CHAR(8) saves one byte compared to VARCHAR(8). Also what I read is that searches in index based on CHAR column could be about 20% faster than in the case of the same index but with VARCHAR column.

Comment: Ivaylo, Plus any involvement with use of temp tables for report preparation effort is reduced by using CHAR(8) vs VARCHAR(20).  Could be significant when there are 50,000+ rows that could be involved.