# How to properly utilize a composite index in JOIN queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, inner-join, database-indexes

I am using MySQL Server 8 and have a MyISAM table containing daily statistics for 'cell' objects for a period of 2 years. In the test table described here there are between 51 and 57 cells (rows) for each day. In a production environment every day a new batch of 80+ cells with daily statistics for the previous day will be added. The columns in the table are many--about 860 counters. The database cannot be normalized, because all columns are equally important. The query produces about 840 columns of statistics for a cluster of user defined list of cells. Each column in the result set is a KPI, which is calculated based on one or more raw counters. The query joins a table containing cluster definitions `clusters_cust` with the main statistical table `h_cell`. Each cell from the cluster is matched with the statistical records in table `h_cell` for the same cell. The user defines a reporting period of several days to several months, selects a defined cluster from table `clusters_cust` and the result set are calculated cells' statistics aggregated per cluster level for for each day of the reporting period.

An example for the contents of `clusters_cust` is below. This table contains a list of cells in the first column 'Cell' and their corresponding Cluster Names in the second column 'Cluster'. One cell can be a part of one or more clusters. Cells that are not a part of any cluster are not present in this table. In this table there could be many clusters (each user is able to define as many clusters as they want) and each cluster can contain a user-defined list of cells--from just a few to tens of thousands.

| Cell | Cluster |
| --- | --- |
| Cell_1 | Cluster_1 |
| Cell_2 | Cluster_1 |
| Cell_3 | Cluster_1 |
| Cell_10 | Cluster_2 |
| Cell_11 | Cluster_2 |
| Cell_12 | Cluster_2 |
| Cell_13 | Cluster_2 |
| Cell_2 | Cluster_3 |
| Cell_14 | Cluster_3 |
| Cell_15 | Cluster_3 |

An example of the contents of table `h_cell` is below. This is the statistical table. It contains daily values of counters for each cell. Each row is the record for specific cell for specific date. Every day a new batch of statistics for 80.000+ cells are inserted.

| Time | Cell | Counter_1 | Counter_2 | Counter_X | Counter_860 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Cell_1 | 3 | 2 | .. | 2 |
| 2023-01-01 | Cell_2 | 4 | 5 | .. | 5 |
| 2023-01-01 | Cell_3 | 1 | 0 | .. | 0 |
| .......... | ...... | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 2023-01-02 | Cell_1 | 6 | 5 | .. | 5 |
| 2023-01-02 | Cell_2 | 3 | 4 | .. | 4 |
| 2023-01-02 | Cell_3 | 4 | 3 | .. | 3 |
| .......... | ...... | .. | .. | .. | .. |

Simplified explanation of the query:

1. The user selects 'Cluster_1';
2. Then the user selects the reporting period - from 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-05, which is 5 days;
3. The optimizer should extract the contents of 'Cluster_1' from table `clusters_cust`, namely 'Cell_1', 'Cell_2' and 'Cell_3';
4. Then it matches these 3 cells with the records for 'Cell_1', 'Cell_2' and 'Cell_3' in table `h_cell` for 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02, 2018-01-03, 2018-01-04 and 2018-01-05;
5. Next step is to sum the values of ('Counter_1' divided by 'Counter_2') for all 3 cells, so that to aggregate them to one cluster value;
6. Since grouing is done by date there should be one cluster value for each of the 5 days in the reporting period.

```
SELECT cluster, Time,
    ROUND(SUM(counter1)/SUM(counter1+counter2)*100,3) AS 'KPI1',
    SUM(counter1) AS 'KPI2',
    .......
    SUM(counterN) AS 'KPI840'
FROM h_cell
INNER JOIN clusters_cust ON clusters_cust.cell = h_cell.cell
WHERE cluster='cluster62'
AND Time>='2018-05-01' AND Time<='2018-06-30'
GROUP BY Time
```

I expected that this query would rely on a composite index in table `h_cell`, which consists of 2 columns--'Cell' and 'Time' (more information about table and index structure is posted below). But the optimizer was unable to use both columns of the index. It used either just the first column 'Cell' and not the second 'Time' or used the 'Time' part of another composite index designed for other type of queries (see below for outputs of `EXPLAIN`). I am joining two tables and applying filters on both of them and the optimizer doesn't know if it's better to start accessing table #1 and then scan table #2, or the other way around.

```
CREATE TABLE `h_cell` (
  Time date NOT NULL,
  Cell char(8) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  LocalCI tinyint NOT NULL,
  Integrity varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  counter1 int DEFAULT NULL,
  counter2 int DEFAULT NULL,
  counter3 double DEFAULT NULL,
  counter4 float DEFAULT NULL,
  ...........
  counter860 int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Cell,Time) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Time` (Time,LocalCI) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

CREATE TABLE `clusters_cust` (
  Cell varchar(11) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Cluster varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  Comment varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Cluster,Cell),
  KEY `Cell` (Cell),
  KEY `Comment` (Comment,Cluster)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM h_cell;
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| h_cell |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | Cell        | A         |       58258 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| h_cell |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | Time        | A         |    39090988 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| h_cell |          1 | Time     |            1 | Time        | A         |         730 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| h_cell |          1 | Time     |            2 | LocalCI     | A         |       15081 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

The primary key is designed to serve queries on cell level--it shows statistics for a given cell and period. I was hoping that it will also help the join queries on cluster level, but this didn't happen.

1. Below is the `EXPLAIN` result for a cluster of **62 cells** and **2 months** reporting period. It seems that from the composite primary key only the first column 'Cell' is used and not the 'Time' part:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows | filtered | Extra                                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clusters_cust | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,Cell        | PRIMARY | 322     | const                        |   63 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h_cell        | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,Time        | PRIMARY | 32      | ee_4g_hua.clusters_cust.Cell |  671 |     5.32 | Using index condition                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

2. For a larger cluster of **3.000 cells** and reporting period of **2 months** the situation is the same--only the first column 'Cell' of the index is used:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows | filtered | Extra                                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clusters_cust | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,Cell        | PRIMARY | 322     | const                        | 4067 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h_cell        | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,Time        | PRIMARY | 32      | ee_4g_hua.clusters_cust.Cell |  671 |     5.32 | Using index condition                     |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

3. But for the same cluster of **3.000 cells** and a shorter reporting period of **1 month** the primary key is not used at all and another index 'Time' is used (this index was designed for another type of queries). Again only the first column of this index is used, but this was expected:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h_cell        | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,Time        | Time    | 3       | NULL                        | 1056817 |   100.00 | Using index condition    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clusters_cust | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Cell        | PRIMARY | 368     | const,ee_4g_hua.h_cell.Cell |       1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

4. For an even larger cluster of **20.000 cells** and reporting period of **2 months** again the primary key is not used, but the 'Time' index (its first column):

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h_cell        | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,Time        | Time    | 3       | NULL                        | 2080777 |   100.00 | Using index condition    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clusters_cust | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Cell        | PRIMARY | 368     | const,ee_4g_hua.h_cell.Cell |       1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

5. To get rid of the `JOIN` I executed a subquery in `WHERE` clause to get the needed list of cells and then `IN` operator was used in the query result. The idea was to make the `WHERE` clause as much as possible look like the `PRIMARY KEY` index structure: to have (cell=A or cell=B or ...) and range scan in Time column.

```
SELECT Time,
    ROUND(SUM(counter1)/SUM(counter1+counter2)*100,3) AS 'KPI1',
    SUM(counter1) AS 'KPI2',
    .......
    SUM(counterN) AS 'KPI840'
FROM h_cell
WHERE cell IN (
    SELECT cell
    FROM clusters_cust
    WHERE cluster='cluster20k')
AND Time>='2018-05-01' AND Time<='2018-06-30'
GROUP BY Time
```

`EXPLAIN` showed the same plan as if there was a `JOIN` and again 'Time' index was used, instead of `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h_cell        | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY,Time        | Time    | 3       | NULL                        | 2080777 |   100.00 | Using index condition    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | clusters_cust | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Cell        | PRIMARY | 368     | const,ee_4g_hua.h_cell.Cell |       1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
```

6. Again `JOIN` was omitted and there was a subquery which directly gets the needed list of cells from a pre-filtered table `clust`. One more time `IN` operator was used.

```
SELECT Time,
    ROUND(SUM(`counter1`)/SUM(`counter1`+`counter2`)*100,3) AS 'KPI1',
    SUM(`counter1`) AS 'KPI2',
    .......
    SUM(`counterN`) AS 'KPI840'
FROM h_cell
WHERE cell IN (SELECT * FROM clust)
AND Time>='2018-05-01' and Time<='2018-06-30' 
GROUP BY Time
```

The result of `EXPLAIN` is below. This time `PRIMARY KEY` index was used, but only the first column from it--'cell'--and not both columns--'cell' and 'Time'. Execution time was so poor that I was not able to wait for query to end.

```
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref              | rows  | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE       | <subquery2> | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             |  NULL |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE       | h_cell      | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,Time        | PRIMARY | 32      | <subquery2>.cell |   671 |     5.32 | Using index condition        |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | clust       | NULL       | ALL  | NULL                | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 20000 |   100.00 | NULL                         |
+----+--------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------------+---------+---------+------------------+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

What should be changed, either in my query or in the table design, for the optimizer to use both 'Cell' and 'Time' members of the primary key index?

Is this possible?

Should there be another more effective index?

Comment: The query falls into the OLAP category. You are joining two tables and applying filter on both of them. The optimizer doesn't know if it's better to start accessing table #1 and then scan table #2, or the other way around. To improve performance of this query you need redundancy. For example, if the table `h_cell` had the `cluster` column it would be trivial to optimize the query and could run real fast.

Comment: @TheImpaler Now I understood thanks to you what is the real issue. I am not sure whether I understood correctly what you meant with "if the table h_cell had the cluster column" - It will be not possible to include `cluster` column in `h_cell` table because a 'cell' could be a part of more than one cluster. Hypotetically if one 'cell' could belong just to one 'cluster' and I have the `cluster` column in `h_cell` table then there will be no need of `clusters_cust` table, so the query will be just a simple `SELECT` without any `JOIN`.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/266284)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: If you could provide some more numbers, I might have some more tips -- how many clusters, how many cels per cluster, how many rows per day, etc.  Also other typical queries.  Maybe a [_Summary Table_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) would be beneficial.

Comment: @RickJames The number of clusters is not controllable value as it depends on the users' preferences - there could be 2, 3 or hundreds of clusters each with a varying number of cells - between 100 and tens of thousands. A cell could be a part of more than one cluster. Regarding the test database: I have 2 years with statistics - 730 days and for each day there are between 51k and 57k cells (the numbers are different as it is just a test table). In production database there are 3 years of stats and each day around 80k new cells are added. I updated my question with additional clarifying info.

Comment: 1 question. PS It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.) Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking what the asker actually wants answered.
PS It is not helpful & is just intrusively noisy (and possibly misleadingly wrong) to restate code in prose. We can read the code. Helpful comments & documentation say why given code was written in terms of the application or internal interfaces when that's not obvious/straightforward.

Comment: "Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments." Why does your last comment contain anything more than an @ that you changed your post? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: "The database cannot be normalized, because all columns are equally important." Why "because"? That is a strange reason to be given with no explanation.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097) etc [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) 
[mre]

Comment: MySQL knows INNER JOIN ON c WHERE d AND e is INNER JOIN WHERE c AND d AND e when optimizing so you should index so that the combined conjuncts gets indexes it neets. This suggests one index on the 3 columns. It suggests subqueries can obscure to the DBMS that the result is just a join of those 3 conjuncts. PS The non-1st column of a compound index is typically is not able to use that index to be joined on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Since alternatives have not worked, I would suggest this alternative.

on your h_cell table, have an index on ( time, cell ).

As for the query, I also added the keyword STRAIGHT_JOIN.  I also qualified each column with the table (alias) to the corresponding columns to better follow which column comes from which table.

Now, from even your own description of data being daily of 51-57k records for a period of roughly 60 days is still running and computing over 300k records.  Now, since you only care about 'cluster62' per this example, I would assume the count is less.  Also, for clarity in the query, you should not have to add the `tick` characters around every column... table.column or alias.column gives the engine explicit qualification to prevent ambiguity of where data comes from, such as `TIME` may be a reserved word, but `h.time` is explicitly a column from the `h` (alias to h_cell table).

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
        cc.cluster,
        h.Time,
        ROUND(  SUM( h.counter1 ) / SUM( h.counter1 + h.counter2 ) * 100,3) AS KPI1,
        SUM( h.counter1 ) AS KPI2,
        .......
        SUM( h.counterN ) AS KPI840
    FROM 
        h_cell h
            INNER JOIN clusters_cust cc
                ON  cc.cluster = 'cluster62' 
                AND h.cell = cc.cell
    WHERE 
            h.Time >= '2018-05-01' 
        AND h.Time <= '2018-06-30'
    GROUP BY 
        h.Time
```

Comment: If there are 62 clusters and only 1 is needed, flipping the PK will lead to reading 1 row and skipping 61.  Not efficient.

Comment: @RickJames, somewhat agree, but each cluster can have many cells per the post.  But which is better.  One cluster, all cells for every day then limited down by date which span years, or starting with just the finite date range and getting the cluster in question.  Just an alternative option I was shooting for.

Comment: As the query stands, it needs a two-dimensional index -- several cells vs time range.

Comment: @DRapp I did many tests of your query. Generally the index is (cell,time) and not (time,cell) as this index serves also simple queries for plain cells. Nevertheless I tried both indexes. Your query with my index (cell,time) showed absolutely the same execution plan for 3k and 20k cells clusters (queries 2 and 4 from the question) - it used 'Time' index. With your index (time,cell) depending on whether 1 or 2 months were queried either 'Time' index was used or the 'PK' index, but just the first column. The drawback is that EXPLAIN showed filtered records twice as many as in my in (cell,time).

Comment: @DRapp You could check my updated question where more clarifying information and example tables are presented.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have?

- Several "clusters"
- Each cluster has several "cells"
- Each cell have several rows in `h_cell`, and more come in over time.
- The query needs to fetch the data for all the cells in one cluster.

Let's restructure.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE h_cell;
CREATE TABLE `h_cell` (
  `Time` date NOT NULL,
   ClusterId SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  -- added
   CellId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    -- changed
  `LocalCI` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Integrity` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `counter1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter2` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter3` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter4` float DEFAULT NULL,
  ...........
  `counter860` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClusterId, `Time`, `CellId`) USING BTREE,  -- Changed
  KEY `Time` (`Time`,`LocalCI`) USING BTREE
  -- (other queries may need other indexes)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Notes/questions:

- What are LocalCI and Integrity for?
- Are you sure MySQL 8 kept the table as MyISAM?
- If 8.0 silently switched the table to InnoDB (or you are forced to later), The PK will probably need changing (for efficiency).
- Check the size of the Ids that I added.
- Make appropriate changes for the "Ids" in the other tables.
- (minor) If you frequently do monthly scans, consider changing from

  ```
      AND  hc.Time>='2018-05-01'
      AND  hc.Time<='2018-06-30'
  ```

  to this formulation:

  ```
      AND  hc.Time>='2018-05-01'
      AND  hc.Time <'2018-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  ```

The principle here is to turn a lot of lookups into a simple index scan.

Resulting query:

```
SELECT  cc.cluster, hc.Time,
        ROUND ,,,
    FROM  clusters_cust AS cc
    JOIN  h_cell AS hc  ON cc.ClusterId = hc.ClusterId
    WHERE  cc.cluster='cluster62'
      AND  hc.Time>='2018-05-01'
      AND  hc.Time <'2018-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    GROUP BY  hc.Time
```

Comment: What is the idea of ```ClusterId``` column? If this is a kind of relationship between cluster and cell this should not be done in ```h_cell``` table, which must be independent from ```clusters_cust``` table. First because one cell can belong to more than one cluster and second because clusters can be deleted, added, modified and those actions cannot be updated in ```h_cell``` table, which is huge and any column updates will be too expensive.

Comment: First to confirm: - ```Several "clusters"``` - YES; - ```Each cluster has several "cells"``` - YES;
- ```Each cell have several rows in h_cell, and more come in over time.``` - YES, each cell have one row for one date, which means for one year there are 365 rows for this cell;
- ```The query needs to fetch the data for all the cells in one cluster``` - YES
Second to answer: - LocalCI and Integrity and used for other purposes and are not relevant; - It looks like tables are still MyISAM; -if in future MyISAM is deprecated I will not upgrade unless I find a solution for InnoDB slow LOAD DATA.